# Flexbox reorder items vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have been trying to figure out how to rearrange two items vertically. I remember doing something like this a while ago with flexbox and have looked up ways to do it again, however when I try and implement the flexbox and give the items an order number nothing happens. What I need is for `.trail-title` to stack below `.trail-items`.

How do I get them to switch places vertically using flexbox?

Here is a JSFidde I created: 
https://jsfiddle.net/tb1sv7n8/15/

```css
#flash-breadcrumbs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.trail-items {
  order: 1;
  height: 1em;
}

.trail-title {
  height: 1em;
}

.breadcrumbs,
.breadcrumbs a {
  color: #544f47;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<nav id="flash-breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumb-trail breadcrumbs">
  <div class="tg-container">
    <h1 class="trail-title">Title of Article: The Love of This</h1>
    <ul class="trail-items">
      <li class="trail-item"><span>This here is the trail: The Love of This</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong CSS selector: The flex container has to be `#flash-breadcrumbs .tg-container` - in your code `.tg-container`, as the child of `#flash-breadcrumbs`, is the only flex item...

Then you can add the `order` settings as desired:

```css
#flash-breadcrumbs .tg-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.trail-items {
  order: 1;
  height: 1em;
}

.trail-title {
  order: 2;
  height: 1em;
}

.breadcrumbs,
.breadcrumbs a {
  color: #544f47;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<nav id="flash-breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumb-trail breadcrumbs">
  <div class="tg-container">
    <h1 class="trail-title">Title of Article: The Love of This</h1>
    <ul class="trail-items">
      <li class="trail-item"><span>This here is the trail: The Love of This</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be much more simple to change `flex-direction` value from `column` to `column-reverse` than to apply different `order` values per every flex item. But this would work only on flex items so you should apply this directly to `.tg-container`. Optimized you CSS:

```css
#flash-breadcrumbs .tg-container {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column-reverse wrap;
  flex-flow: column-reverse wrap;
}

.trail-items,
.trail-title {
  height: 1em;
}

.breadcrumbs,
.breadcrumbs a {
  color: #544f47;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<nav id="flash-breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumb-trail breadcrumbs">
  <div class="tg-container">
    <h1 class="trail-title">Title of Article: The Love of This</h1>
    <ul class="trail-items">
      <li class="trail-item"><span>This here is the trail: The Love of This</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `flex` to the `.tg-container` div since it's the parent of both and change the value of the `order` property to `-1` for the `.trail-items` div, which will then place it above the `.trail-title`:

```css
.tg-container {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap; not necessarry*/
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap; /* this is enough */
  /*flex-direction: column; not necessarry*/
}

.trail-items {
  order: -1; /* modified */
  height: 1em;
}

.trail-title {
  height: 1em;
}

.breadcrumbs, .breadcrumbs a {
  color: #544f47;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<nav id="flash-breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumb-trail breadcrumbs">
  <div class="tg-container">
    <h1 class="trail-title">Title of Article: The Love of This</h1>
    <ul class="trail-items">
      <li class="trail-item">
        <span>This here is the trail: The Love of This</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```